# Can VRay be used with Blender and is there any decent documentation on how to do this?

Tags: rendering

I am an architect looking to get into Blender 3D, but would like to utilize VRay for visualizations. DOes anyone know if this is available and if it is could someone point me to some good documentation on how to set it up?

Comment: Try looking here - https://www.chaosgroup.com/vray/blender

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I'll check that out.